# Objects pulse to sound?

Tags: game-engine

Is there any way to make an object pulse to sound? I want to make my camera pulse to the beat of some music WITHOUT ANIMATION.

Comment: You mean sound to pulse? Try baking sound to F-Curves for that

Comment: It's harder than you might think, you need fast fourier transformation (FFT) and provide the sound data to Blender in real-time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082431/frequency-analysis-in-python

Comment: @stacker Ah, yes realtime is a completely different beast.